# How to use phpMyAdmin to import ods file for Null value fields with default empty space

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, ods

I want to use phpMyAdmin to import data from ods file to MySQL / Mariadb table. The table contains some fields like below:

```
city_desc CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

It is NOT Null, Default is empty space.

Once import, because the column has no value, it prompts an error that the column cannot be null. Is it possible to import those no value columns as empty space instead?

Comment: Does the ods file attempt to add NULL to `city_desc` - You can replace these instances so as to fix it or 
Modify the shared line to be `city_descc CHAR(1) DEFAULT ''`

Comment: How is "the column has no value" represented in the "import data"?